# Error when updating excel sheet from Macros........?

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheets with Macros that updates information like timelines, completion dates, etc.. from other excel files. It was working fine until I got this: [Pop up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbjgL.png) which I just yes and everything is fine but it now opens up a dialog box and I specified the file path so I don't know if I need to select the file and open it?

[Dialog asking for file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o69sg.png)

```js
Sub GetTimelineMemberFirst()

Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook

'UPDATE w/ path to Files
    Set wbXL = CreateObject("S:\Premier\020218\Initial\17314 - Merger.xlsm")

    'Get IV timeline
    Sheets("Merger - Feb 2018").Unprotect
    Range("A17:G90").Select
    Selection.Clear
'UPDATE w/ SOW name
    Windows("17314 - Merger Merger Work statements.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Timeline").Select
    Range("A2:G80").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("weekly spreadsheet.xls").Activate
'UPDATE w/ WCM tab name
    Sheets("Merger - Feb 2018").Select
    Range("A17").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone _
       , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
       :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("B17:B90").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    'get lead timeline
    Range("A349:G900").Select
    Selection.Clear
'UPDATE w/ SOW name
    Windows("17314 - Merger Merger Work statements.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Lead").Select
    Range("A1:G140").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("weekly spreadsheet.xls").Activate
'UPDATE w/ WCM tab name
    Sheets("Merger - Feb 2018").Select
    Range("A349").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("B349:B900").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    
    Range("A79:F79").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$79:$F$335").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="="
    
    Range("A1").Select
    
    
    wbXL.Close
    
End Sub​
```

Comment: Try turning off alerts, put this after the sub name: `Excel.Application.DisplayAlerts = False`

Comment: This won't have an impact on other spreadsheets? I have like 30 spreadsheets in this workbook so I don't want to jack up 1000s+ lines of code.

Comment: No, setting display alerts to false just prevents Excel pop ups, Excel will choose the "Yes" option in the pop up window by default, the reason why the dialog window appears is because you have formulas or named cells referencing external workbooks, check the "Name manager" to see if any named cell is referencing external workbooks and correct them, go to "Name manager" and check the TestCUID" name reference.

Comment: Well, the macro still doesn't run once I close the dialog and window popup

Comment: What kind of error it's showing?, here is an explanation of the first pop up [Name already exist](https://superuser.com/questions/474321/why-does-excel-now-give-me-already-existing-name-range-warning-on-copy-sheet)

Comment: Shows nothing really. It just jerks a bit and finishes but I don't see any updates coming in from the other excel file I listed to update from

Comment: `Set wbXL = CreateObject("S:\Premier\020218\Initial\17314 - Merger.xlsm")` is pretty suspect already. Why not `Set wbXL = Application.Workbooks.Open("S:\Premier\020218\Initial\17314 - Merger.xlsm")` instead?

Comment: Well, 
the file is in a virtual drive I don't know if having a virtual network drive would cause any issues using your suggested edit

Comment: @SkywardSword Mat's suggestion shouldn't harm anything related to it being a network drive. Windows treats it (essentially) like a local drive once mapped. Also, you may benefit from trimming down on the activate and select statements as these, in my opinion, complicate things (they also slow things down as well).

Comment: Any suggestions on what I can do to get the Macro to pull info from the excel sheet? I didn't write this VBA so I'm trying to not mess things up lol